# How to write parameterized query in CodeIgniter using where and or_where

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
$where = "`b`.`User_Type` = 6 AND `a`.`payment_status` = 2 OR (`a`.`payment_status` = 1 AND `a`.`approvedStatus` = 2)";

$this->db->where($where);
```

**I am unable to write the above where condition like $this->db->where(array())...
OR using any other pattern we use in CodeIgniter. Someone please help to write the right query.**

I don't want to use direct SQL query like first line.

Forgive me if the question waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter have 2 different way with query builder and direct row query

Below is the way with query builder

```
$this->db->where("b.User_Type = 6 AND a.payment_status = 3 OR (a.payment_status = 1 AND a.approvedStatus = 2)");
```

also you can do with row query

```
$this->db->query('SELECt * from TABLE WHERE ? AND ? OR ?')
```

Comment: I think both methods are approx the same. Both have raw SQL queries. 
I am trying to find out any method where I don't need to write a raw SQL query...